# What do the phrases 「ことに」 at the end of a sentence and 「を巡り」 mean?

Tags: manga, renyōkei, omission

Here is the sentence relating to my question:

> 院生たちに慰問に現れた葉子**を巡り**、再び力石とジョーは拳を交える**ことに**。

1. For the word 「を巡り」, does it mean 'concerning' which is similar to the meaning of 「を巡って」?
2. For the word 「ことに」, is it a colloquial short form of 「ことになる」?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. For the word 「を[巡]{めぐ}り」, does it mean 'concerning' which
>    is similar to the meaning of 「を巡って」?

Exactly.  「～～を巡り」 is a little more formal than 「～～を巡って」.  Both express the source of dispute (or a fight in this case).

> 2. For the word 「ことに」, is it a colloquial short form of 「ことになる」?

Precisely.  When what is left unsaid is clear to the readers from the context, words are often omitted like that.